# How to secure server while using jwt

Tags: security, jwt

*Hi, Currently we are working on a web application and we are using **JWT** for authentication once user login successfully for the respective request.
My question is If some how the secret key for generating signature is out so  server to ensure security the secret key need to be updated and server need to be down and user must be asked to login again.
Is there is any better solution in such condition?*

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about what to do if the private key is compromised?  Yes, then you need to update to a new private key and invalidate everybody's sessions.  There is no better solution because you cannot distinguish between a validly generated session and a maliciously generated session.